# Send data or a file to another application on Mac

Tags: c#, objective-c, macos, file, xamarin

My program generates a script for another application. How can I also make opening this script in that application? And is it possibly to be done without using an external file? My program is written in Xamarin and C# (due to use of one C# library), but obviously any Objective-C solution is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the ungrounded minus, now nobody will watch and answer my question...

Comment: Is the other application scriptable?

Comment: That's probably because you only want your answer without sharing important information like whether your application is sandboxed.

Comment: @Willeke no. It can only open files. Probably, it is the answer

Comment: @ElTomato to be precise, I use Xamarin (coz I need to use a library written in C#). I guess, it is not sandboxed. I didn't know about this option before, thus hadn't said anything about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the only way is to write information to a file and to open this file programmatically with another application. Class [*NSWorkspace*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Desktop_Image_Dictionary_Keys) helps to do that:

```
NSString *data = @"Some data";
NSString *filename = @"Some filename";
[data writeToFile:path
       atomically:NO
         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
            error:nil];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:filename
                        withApplication:@"Graphviz"];
```

And the code for C#:

```
using AppKit;
using System.IO;
...
string data = "Some data";
string filename = "Some filename";
File.WriteAllText (filename, data);
NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.OpenFile (filename, "Graphviz");
```

Probably, to do that without using files external application must support AppleScript, but it doesn't.